# How to label or plot only the previous nth bar with Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I try to highlight only the previous 5th bar within the Pine Script Editor.

I found the Pine Script always outputs a range of bars from the present like this:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Previous Day Retrace", overlay = true)
l = label.new(bar_index, close)
label.delete(l[5])
```

How can I just label or plot only one bar at each time?  Looking for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can plot the label at bar_index-4 and then delete upto previous label i.e. b[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASbe3.png)

```
//@version=5
indicator("Previous Day Retrace", overlay = true)
l = label.new(bar_index-4, high)
label.delete(l[1])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is simpler than I thought. I just modified the style a bit for better label locations.

//@version=5
indicator("Previous Day Retrace (5th and 10th)", overlay = false)

//5,10
l5 = label.new(bar_index-5, na,text="Prev 5th", color=color.green, style=label.style_label_down, yloc=yloc.abovebar)
label.delete(l5[1])
‘
l10 = label.new(bar_index-10, na,text="Prev 10th", color=color.green, style=label.style_label_down, yloc=yloc.abovebar)
label.delete(l10[1])